# puppet manifest usage with hash

Tags: puppet, hash

I'm struggling to get this to work and don't understand where I'm going wrong, can someone please guide me on how to correct?

Basically I want to get an array in my nodes.pp, which is then used by my templates file by cycling through it and writing a line of each element:

nodes.pp:

```
    node test{
        net::addr { 'routing':
          $routes = {
            route1 => {
                address => '172.29.54.70',
                netmask => '255.255.255.0',
                gateway => '172.29.54.65',
                dev     => 'eth0',
            },
            route2 => {
                address => '192.168.1.3',
                netmask => '255.255.255.0',
                gateway => '192.168.1.1',
                dev     => 'eth3',
            },
          }
        }
}
```

When I run the puppet client i keep getting the following:

err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '='; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/ test.pp:3 on node test.myincorp.net

addr.pp

```
define net::addr (
  $address='',
  $netmask='',
  $gateway='',
  $dev='',
) {

  file { "route-${name}":
    ensure  => 'present',
    mode    => '0644',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    path    => "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-${name}",
    content => template('network/addr.erb'),
}
}
```

Template: addr.erb:

```
<% routes.each do |route| -%>
  <%= route['address'] %>  <%= route['netmask'] %> <%= route['gateway'] %> <%= route['dev'] %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Can someone help me with fixing the above please?

Thanks Dan

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're intending to pass in a array of routes to net::addr in a routes name, but you've defined it as taking the 4 keys of each route rather then the route array. Try the following and see if it works any better.

```
node test{
    net::addr { 'routing':
        routes => {
            route1 => {
                address => '172.29.54.70',
                netmask => '255.255.255.0',
                gateway => '172.29.54.65',
                dev     => 'eth0',
            },
            route2 => {
                address => '192.168.1.3',
                netmask => '255.255.255.0',
                gateway => '192.168.1.1',
                dev     => 'eth3',
            },
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
define net::addr (
  $routes={},
) {
    file { "route-${name}":
        ensure  => 'present',
        mode    => '0644',
        owner   => 'root',
        group   => 'root',
        path    => "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-${name}",
        content => template('network/addr.erb'),
    }
}
```

Edit: Fixed typo, padding to get by edit character limit

Comment: Hi,I copied and pasted your suggestions above but I still got: `err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '='; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes/test.pp:108 on node test.myincorp.net`. Any other thoughts, its driving me a bit crazy this problem. Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear the line in question that the error is pointing to relates to is "routes = {"

Comment: Sorry, typoed the =>. Try with that fixed?